# ALB forward traffic to two target groups (IP & Lambda) at the same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an ALB forwarding traffic into IP target group and I'm trying to forward the traffic beside the IP target group into a Lambda function at the same time. In other words, the requests receieved by an ALB should be forwarded to IP and Lambda target groups.

Is duplicating the traffic or forward the same traffic into two target groups at the same time possible? if not, what are the alternatives?

I've gone throug the docs but as far as I understand this is not possible because eventhough you can have multiple target groups per listener rule but you can't duplicate the traffic into the groups, you can only weight them and the traffic would be split based on that but that's not gonna work for me.

Why I need to do this? I want to apply some filters on the traffic to log specific requests based on some business logic and enbaling access logs of ALB won't do the trick because I have to wait for 5 minutes to get log files on S3 but I need to get the logs in real-time.

Comment: Its not possible. You need fully custom solution.

Comment: What you are proposing is not possible. A load balancer will not distribute a single request to multiple targets, ever. You might look at AWS VPC Traffic Mirroring to see if that would work for you https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/mirroring/what-is-traffic-mirroring.html

Comment: @MarkB This possible but it's too complicated because there is the UDP limitation and then you have to add EC2 instance before a NLB to process the packets again and convert then into HTTP protocol from GENEVE protocol, after that, you have to forward those requests to endpoint/lambda or even ALB
Cost wise and complexity wise this is too much for my use case. 
Thanks a lot for the suggestion tho!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called `Traffic Mirroring` or `Dark Release`

It has limitation on certain target resources:

- Network Interface
- Network Load Balancer
- Gateway Load Balancer

For further details https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/mirroring/traffic-mirroring-targets.html